# Flexbox elements nested inside of inline-flex don't properly fill the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a dropdown-style menu, but I'm running into some unexpected issues that appear to be caused by flexbox. The menu items that are hovered to open the dropdown are being styled using styles like the following to achieve a centered layout:

```css
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: inline-flex;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
```

The inline-flex display seems to be causing conflicts inside of the dropdowns that open under these menu items. The contents of the panels seem to want to collapse to as little space as possible (even less than what I would expect for an inline-block element with more space to grow). For example, I have 2 sections inside of a dropdown. I want both to expand as much as possible (up to 20ems for the link size), but each section tries to take as little room as possible, and the panel even overlaps. Here's a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t56cLyb/8/)** of my example (I apologize for the slightly messy example, but I wanted to keep it as close to my case as possible for now). If you remove the "inline-flex" block in the example, then you can see the intended behavior, but I would prefer to not have to do that to solve the issue.

I think this issue is related to [a known flexbox issue with inline-flex containers struggling to size column wrapped elements](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-14), since the parent is flex column. That said, the children are flex row, so I would assume those to calculate their size appropriately.

Upon further inspection, simply replacing the inline-flex rules with a simple `display:inline-block;` will replicate the issue. Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t56cLyb/19/)** of the example.

```css
.navigation-bar__wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.navigation-bar__wrapper .navigation-bar__dropdown-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  /* NOTE: Killing this line seems to fix the issue */
  display:inline-block;
}
.navigation-bar__wrapper .navigation-bar__dropdown-wrapper:hover > .navigation-bar__menu-wrapper {
  visibility: visible;
}
.navigation-bar__wrapper .navigation-bar__dropdown-wrapper > .navigation-bar__menu-wrapper {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
.navigation-bar__wrapper .navigation-bar__menu-wrapper {
  background-color: #FFF;
  /* NOTE: You can uncomment this line if you want the hovering effect */
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #AAA;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 1px;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}
.navigation-bar__menu {
  display: flex;
  height: 325px;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper .navigation-bar__menu-item-title {
  max-width: 20em;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper .navigation-bar__menu-item-description {
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  max-width: 20em;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper .navigation-bar__featured-image {
  width: 193px;
  height: 93px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-section {
  padding: 0 5px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-section + .navigation-bar__menu-section {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-section .navigation-bar__menu-section-title-wrapper {
  padding-right: 2em;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-section .navigation-bar__menu-section-content-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  margin-top: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
.navigation-bar__menu-section .navigation-bar__menu-section-content-wrapper > * {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
.navigation-panel-drilldown__wrapper .navigation-panel-drilldown__static-trigger {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.navigation-panel-drilldown__wrapper .navigation-panel-drilldown__interactions-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.navigation-panel-drilldown__wrapper .navigation-panel-drilldown__drilldown-content .navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper {
  display: block;
}
.navigation-bar__menu.has-panel-drilldown {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navigation-bar__menu.has-panel-drilldown .navigation-bar__menu-section {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navigation-bar__menu.has-panel-drilldown .navigation-bar__menu-section-title-wrapper.navigation-panel-drilldown__drilldown-title-wrapper {
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar__wrapper">
  <ul class="navigation-bar__dropdown-containers-wrapper">
    <li class="navigation-bar__dropdown-wrapper navigation-bar__data-menu">
      <span class="navigation-bar__dropdown-title-wrapper">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="navigation-bar__dropdown-title">I'm what is hovered to open the menu</a>
      </span>
      <div class="navigation-bar__menu-wrapper">
        <div class="navigation-bar__menu has-panel-drilldown">
          <div class="navigation-bar__menu-section navigation-panel-drilldown__wrapper">
            <div class="navigation-bar__menu-section-title-wrapper navigation-panel-drilldown__drilldown-title-wrapper">
              <div class="navigation-bar__menu-section-title">Drilldown section</div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation-panel-drilldown__interactions-wrapper">
              <div class="navigation-panel-drilldown__static-triggers-wrapper">
                <div class="navigation-panel-drilldown__static-trigger selected">Section 1</div>
                <div class="navigation-panel-drilldown__static-trigger">Section 2</div>
                <div class="navigation-panel-drilldown__static-trigger">Section 3</div>
                <div class="navigation-panel-drilldown__static-trigger">Section 4</div>
              </div>
              <div class="navigation-panel-drilldown__drilldown-content-wrapper">
                <div class="navigation-panel-drilldown__drilldown-content">
                  <a href="/noop" target="_blank" class="navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="navigation-bar__menu-item-title">Some long option name that is too compressed</div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="/noop" target="_blank" class="navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="navigation-bar__menu-item-title">Some other option name</div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="/noop" target="_blank" class="navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="navigation-bar__menu-item-title">last option name that's long</div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="navigation-bar__menu-section">
            <div class="navigation-bar__menu-section-title-wrapper">
              <div class="navigation-bar__menu-section-title">Extra</div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation-bar__menu-section-content-wrapper">
              <a href="/noop" target="_blank" class="navigation-bar__menu-item-wrapper">
                <div class="navigation-bar__menu-item-title">Extra option</div>
                <div class="navigation-bar__menu-item-description">Some long description name about the extra option here</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue with removing the inline-flex?

Comment: That will break another set of styles that has been a bit of a pain to setup. Perhaps I'm being naive in thinking that finding a solution to the odd nested flexbox issue will be more ideal than reworking the way the menu bar works though.

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself.